# What is minimal requirements for running simplest graphical application on Linux box

Tags: linux, graphics, development, armbian

Having little Linux box running Armbian on Orange Pi, I want to develop on C++ small graphical application which will just read frame from remote IP camera and show it on screen connected to HDMI port.
No any login widows, no any graphical desktops, no any taskbars, no any buttons and labels. Just one borderless window where I show picture read from remote IP camera right after booting of the box and till the end of the world or electricity.

Which minimal set of graphical software (libraries) do I need for this purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRM/KMS can be used to output graphics in Linux, so you don't have need to have the X.org server installed. As to how to use it, you can check the MPV sources:

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/video/out/vo_drm.c

https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/brezillon-drm-kms.pdf

---

If you're going to use X.org/X11, it's a whole different affair:

[http://mech.math.msu.su/~nap/2/GWindow/xintro.html](http://mech.math.msu.su/%7Enap/2/GWindow/xintro.html)

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#C

https://www.geeks3d.com/20120102/programming-tutorial-simple-x11-x-window-code-sample-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/

Comment: Ok. It seems, DRM/KMS is what I need. But dammit, according to what I saw in vo_drm.c, there must be done huge work. All by hands!
Anyway, thanks